# Combining probabilities from uncorrelated binary observations of a categorical variable

Tags: probability, categorical-data, conditional-probability, independence

(Somewhat similar to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/389509/326258) relating to binary outcomes).

I have `N` binary probability observations of a categorical random variable with cardinality `M+1`. For example:

- Observer 1 says `A` with an independently calibrated `80%` chance of being correct
- Observer 2 says `A` with an `70%` chance of being correct
- Observer 3 says `C` with a `65%` chance of being correct
- Observer `N` says `M` with a `2%` chance of being correct
- ...But there is a possibility of null outcome `0` (hence `M+1`), which none of the observers directly measure (they'd just each report very low probabilities of some non-null outcome).

Each observer measures the probability of some non-null outcome vs all possible others (including null). There's always at least one observer per possible non-null outcome, but (as suggested above) some of the outcomes will have multiple observers.

Is there some framework of assumptions that could allow quantification of which outcome is most likely and a decent estimate of its posterior probability?

For example, even if we can say the observers are uncorrelated and the prior is uniform - it seems like there's a good amount of information encoded in the observations but I'm not sure how they could be synthesized together?